# CSS vertical align with different image heights

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically align the items in the first row for all possible image heights:

[image]

See here: https://lawncarepro.co.uk/code-test/

I have tried the solutions listed here [How to vertically align an image inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div) including:

- Setting .p-c to inline-block with height: 100%; and using vertical align middle on all three columns in the first row
- Doing the above but with a new div for the first row
- Using position: relative; and position: absolute; (this generally pushes things out of the box or changes the column order)
- Using position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); on the columns in the first row

Comment: please refer to the  flex property  and flex-direction: column  it will help you I guess

Comment: @Rijil I don't quite understand, are you saying adding flex values to the columns will enable vertical-align: middle; to work?

Comment: Please share your code, we can't debug an image :)

Comment: @Thomas the URL should allow you to look at it

Comment: @user16421 I know, but try to follow SO's guidelines for creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Thomas it's not really practical to add it to a jsfiddle or similar due to the WP column shortcodes I'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These codes will guide you. and for bottom section can use flex too (width=50%) there is no need for float left.

```css
.main-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.main-wrapper .p-c-top {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-wrapper .p-c-top .content-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 33.333%;
}

.main-wrapper .p-c-top .content-col img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="p-c-top">
            <div class="content-col">
                <img src="https://ir-uk.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=lawncarepro-21&language=en_GB&l=li2&o=2&a=B0099LETKS" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content-col">
               <h4>overal value</h4>
               <p>stars</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-col">
               <h4>price</h4>
               <p><a href="#">check on amazon</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-c-bot"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have added these attributes to my set-up (other than the red borders) but am still stuck with the flexbox on the left. I can't get it to distribute evenly: https://i.imgur.com/fFAV682.png

Comment: still didn't change the bottom section, I see float left and clear fix in your codes. create another parent div for bot section and remove float:left. rewrite css

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going with [CSS-Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) (and make changes as required):

I quickly played around the code and came up with this.

```
  .p-c {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    grid-template-rows: max-content max-content;
    align-items: center;
   }
```

**Please Note:** One of the div's is empty. So, you can manually set the `display:none;` if required. And align items are required.
With Grids there are too many ways to layout our HTML. Just do some R&D :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried flexbox? You can create 3 dives with a parent div which has display flex and then justify them horizontally and vertically to center.So with every image the parent height automatically will be set due to image height and other items remain in center.

Comment: When I set add display: flex; to .p-c this gets rid of the columns (everything turns into a single row). Setting the other columns also as display: flex; doesn't fix this. I'm not sure if a flexbox would work here or if there's a different way I can implement it.

Comment: don't set flex to .p-c . create another parent div just for above section. Seperate them. and then create 3 div inside the new div. It seems you are not familiar with flex-box.

Comment: this has helped, but the content is only appearing on the left-hand side (see: https://lawncarepro.co.uk/code-test/). I have tried altering margin and width settings but haven't been able to get it to distribute horizontally